# How to run all cron jobs in /etc/cron.d using one crontab?

Tags: docker, cron

I have several cron jobs in /etc/cron.d in my Docker container, which lives inside a pod.

As a requirement, I need to run cron or an equivalent of it as a non-root user - in this case, I have found that supercronic could be a viable option as it is designed for containers. supercronic works by specifying a crontab it should run e.g. /usr/local/bin/supercronic CRONTAB

What are all the ways I could use supercronic to run the cron jobs in /etc/cron.d? Do I need to forgo the actual .cron files in cron.d and just have my logic in the crontab? Is there a way to get my crontab to run everything inside cron.d? Do I need to create my own script that my crontab would run, which would then run everything in cron.d?